# How to make [SerializeField] work with Play Mode Tests? (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, testing

[Unity using version 2020.3.30f1]

I'm trying to make PlayMode tests run in Unity. I would like to test my CreateGameControllerScript on its functions and validations. I've created some animations on some objects and fire them with a co-routine. Here is some code just to give you an idea:

```
public class CreateGameControllerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
  
  [SerializeField] public ToggleGroup select_Worlds;
    [SerializeField] public GameObject Warning_Not_AllOptions_Selected;  

    private void Awake()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(select_Worlds);
        Assert.IsNotNull(Warning_Not_AllOptions_Selected);
    }

public void StartGenerationOfInfiniteRunnerGame()
    {
        if (selectedWorldType != WorldType.None)
        {
            // DO Stuff  

        }
        else {

            if (!select_Worlds.AnyTogglesOn())
            {
                List<Toggle> myToggles = select_Worlds.GetComponentsInChildren<Toggle>().ToList();
                myToggles.ForEach(delegate(Toggle tog)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(SmallWarningAnimation(tog)); 
                });
            }
                
            Warning_Not_AllOptions_Selected.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the PlayMode Test I'm trying to run is failing, assertions are always null. The SerializeFields are set in my scene. I was expecting that these tests would be run while having knowledge of the scene/run. I've looked online and all I could find is using a  'var utility = RunEditorUtilityInTheBackground();' but this is for an older version of Unity.
Also I read about testing but they are not using serializefield. Just like these are really solid tests: https://videlais.com/2021/03/02/working-with-unity-test-framework-part-2-writing-play-mode-tests/

I can use Prefabs to instantiate, but still they need to get an assigned serializefield. Am I missing something obvious here?

The test:

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator CreateGameMainUITestsWithEnumeratorPasses()
{
    // this won't be found  ... var utility = RunEditorUtilityInTheBackground();

    var gameObject = new GameObject();
    var panelLogic = gameObject.AddComponent<CreateGameControllerScript>();
    
    panelLogic.StartGenerationOfInfiniteRunnerGame();

    // maybe put in the play clip duration?
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

    Assert.IsTrue(panelLogic.Warning_Not_AllOptions_Selected.activeSelf);
}
```

How can I use my in scene objects for the tests? How can I maybe load or tests my script using the correct objects? For anyone answering, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All I did to solve this when I encountered it was to call `UnityEngine.SceneManagement.LoadScene` during the method which had SetUp attribute and call `GameObject.Find(objectName)` in the test to find the object from the scene. Actually, it appears that the tests do not have the knowledge of the scene if you don't load it. This article might be helpful.

https://medium.com/xrpractices/practical-playmode-testing-in-unity3d-5ea455bf28b0